# How can I make a read-only Linux system (which uses unionfs) read/write for the duration of upgrades?

Tags: filesystems, embedded

Assuming having an embedded linux application, and for protection against corruption from example abrupt power offs, you implement a read only system with union fs. But then, how is it possible to make the system read write again, in case you need to perform some software update?

Comment: Your best solution is going to be to `rsync` from the union layer into the bottom layer.